# eXist-db xPath functions XQueryService: lowercase()

Tags: java, xpath, xquery, exist-db

I am new with eXist and xPath. I am trying to use the lowercase function. Here's my java code.

```
CompiledExpression compiled = xQueryService.compile("/realestatedata/agents/author/name[lower_case(text())='" + authorName.toLowerCase() + "']");
```

It gives the following error.

```
Caused by: org.exist.xquery.XPathException: exerr:ERROR err:XPST0017 Function lower_case()  is not defined in module namespace: http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions [at line 1, column 36] [at line 1, column 36]
```

I read in the documentation that modules have to be included so I put the following in conf.xml under xquery->builtin-modules.

```
<module uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"  class="org.exist.xquery.functions.fn.FnModule" />
```

I am getting the same error after an exist restart. I've also tried changing the XQueryService from `org.xmldb.api.modules.XQueryService` to `org.xmldb.api.modules.XMLResource`

Comment: what about `"/realestatedata/agents/author/name[lower-case(text())='"...`, i.e. with a dash "-" and not underscore "_"?

Comment: @paul-t is right. You misspelled the function name. And there's need to add anything to conf.xml for the XPath functions module to work; these will work out of the box. Also, as your database grows, you can improve performance of these queries by adding an index to the name element. A range index or full text index would be appropriate. See http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/indexing.xml.

Comment: Thank you. It was a typo. My collection will be a few gb in size so I am going to look at indexes.

Answer (score 0):

> You misspelled the function name
>
> "/realestatedata/agents/author/name[lower-case(text())='"